# Namespace missing in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime app project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 runtime app. The [InkPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.inkpresenter%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class which was available in Windows Phone 8 is not there in 8.1.

Now, 8.1 should be backward compatible with 8 and that all the apps that used the InkPresenter class in Windows Phone 8 can run on 8.1 too. So my guess(and I can be wrong in assuming this) is that the Inkpresenter class should be there in Windows Phone 8.1 too but might be under a different namespace. Otherwise, how could the apps of Windows Phone 8 using the Inkpresenter class be run on Windows Phone 8.1.

Is my guess true? If yes then please specify how to find the new namespace.

Comment: The InkPresenter is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\System.Windows.dll` but for some reason it does not want to be referenced automatically.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder...A DLL has to be referenced if a class defined in it is used....And if we can't reference the DLL, how would we use its classes?

Comment: @avinash you need to understand this, you can't use sliverlight api's in new winrt api's.

Comment: @Vyas_27...can you point me to a link which tells me about all these frameworks and how they are interrelated

Comment: @Vyas_27 I think this is a Silverlight 8.1 app, not a Universal App.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime XAML based app which targets new sets of common WinRT API's for Windows Phone 8.1 . And Windows Phone 8 apps target sliverlight api's, if you want to use the same api's in Windows Phone 8 in your Windows Phone 8.1 then try writing Windows Phone 8.1 sliverlight apps, this will solve your problem.  [This will help you understand better](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642084%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: @Vyas_27...If the class is not available in Windows Phone 8.1, how will the Windows 8 apps using the Inkpresenter class run in 8.1? Won't they search for the class during compilation on 8.1 and won't they give a compilation error if class is not defined(which it is not in 8.1)?

Comment: the class is not available for the universal app api's that you are currently targeting but it is present for the sliverlight api's for both Windows Phone 8 & 8.1.

Comment: @Vyas_27...so what you are saying is that while running on 8.1, the windows 8 app using InkPresenter would use the Silverlight apis to search for classes during compilation.

Comment: yes it will because it is build on top of it not the new combined winrt api's.