# Microsoft.Phone assembly is missing in Windows Phone 8.1 app project

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, reverse-geocoding

Microsoft.Phone assembly is missing in Windows Phone 8.1 app project.

I am trying to use the following class:
ReverseGeocodeQuery

This class is registered at the following namespace:
Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Services

Specifically, I need to capture the current city and state of a phone.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: What do you intend by "Microsoft.Phone assembly is missing in Windows Phone 8.1 app project"? The ReverseGeocodeQuery is flagged as compatible with 8.1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.maps.services.reversegeocodequery%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: I am unable resolve the class ReverseGeocodeQuery within my Wiindows Phone 8.1 project. The namespace Microsoft.Phone just doesn't exist when I attempt to use the namespace.

Comment: Did you add the ID_CAP_MAP capability under the capabilities tab?
The namespace is part of the SDK so if you can target WP8.1 you should be able to get them

Comment: Basic question... Did you try to add the reference to the namespace on your project?

Comment: I added location as a capability in the manifest. I do not see any additional references for assemblies to include. In addition, I am not familiar with "ID_CAP_MAP".

Comment: When you right-click the "References" folder in your project, and try to "add", do you have Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Services in the list?

Comment: WinRT does not support that assembly. I resolved my issue with a different class. See link for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692120/getting-civicaddress-on-windows-phone-8-1/23695748?noredirect=1#comment38713169_23695748

Comment: You were talking about a Windows Phone 8.1 project..;

Comment: Yes. Aren't they both based on WinRT?

Comment: For all the Maps part, there is a difference between Windows Phone 8.1 world and windows 8.1 world, typically for the APIs

Answer (score 1):

Found this very helpful answer on SO :

"You are writing a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime XAML based app which targets new sets of common WinRT API's for Windows Phone 8.1 . And Windows Phone 8 apps target sliverlight api's, if you want to use the same api's in Windows Phone 8 in your Windows Phone 8.1 then try writing Windows Phone 8.1 sliverlight apps, this will solve your problem. This will help you understand better"

[Namespace missing in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime app project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652107/namespace-missing-in-windows-phone-8-1-runtime-app-project)